# Zend Navigation Uri and BaseUrl

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view, zend-navigation, view-helpers

I am setting up zend navigation in my website and I've got a issue while developing locally.

My navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
 <nav>
    <page1>
        <label>Site</label>
        <uri>/</uri>
        <pages>
            <page1_1>
                <label>Home</label>
                <uri>/</uri>
            </page1_1>
            <page1_2>
                <label>Contact</label>
                <uri>/contact</uri>
            </page1_2>
        </pages>
    </page1>
  </nav>
</config>
```

Rendering the menu

```
<?=$this->navigation()->menu();?>
```

HTML Output

```
<ul class="navigation">
 <li class="active">
    <a href="/">Site</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
```

I develop the project in a subfolder Ex.: http://localhost/project/public. And zend navigation uri shows link as http://localhost/contact instated of http://localhost/project/public/contact

How could I apply my baseUrl over uri?

Comment: show the code on how are you generating that link which points to http://localhost/contact

Comment: @emaillenin I just inserted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specify the whole route in your xml file:

```
    <home>
        <label>Home</label>    
        <route>home</route>
        <module>default</module>
        <controller>index</controller>
        <action>index</action>
    </home>
```

this is a named route as well as specified by module, controller, action.

Comment: Specify the module, controller, action works but It's bit boring to write, Is it the one solution?

Comment: you could always add a base tag in your layout that should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the standard way of generating URLs, you can set the base url before generating them as explained here.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.rewritebase

```
$request->setBaseUrl('/project/public/');
```

Comment: Well My baseUrl works in the view but I need the solution that works with zend navigation